# Вывод сообщений с группировкой по дате

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать следующее. Имеются выбранные из базы данных сообщения. В цикле вывести - выводятся. Но как их сгруппировать по датам, чтобы получилась структура такого вида:

```
                       =========== 25-04-2012 ========
          текст сообщения                            25-04-2012
          текст сообщения                            25-04-2012
          текст сообщения                            25-04-2012

                      =========== 12-04-2012 ========
          текст сообщения                            12-05-2012
          текст сообщения                            12-05-2012

                      =========== 3-04-2012 ========
          текст сообщения                            3-04-2012
          текст сообщения                            3-04-2012
          текст сообщения                            3-04-2012
          текст сообщения                            3-04-2012
```

Наподобие как в "Одноклассниках" сделаны личные сообщения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$req = mysql_query($query);
$curdate = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) {
   if ($curdate != $row['date']) {
      $curdate = $row['date'];
      print '<h3>=========== '.$curdate.' =============</h3>'
   }
   // ..... вывод сообщения
}
```

В запросе сообщения надо отсортировать по дате по убыванию.

Comment: А я всё вокруг, да около хожу уже 2 дня. Благодарствую!!!